# Python flask restless search query to find date regardless of time

Tags: python, flask, flask-restless

I'm using Flask and Flask-Restless and have a model that looks like this:

```
class Task(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Task'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    stable_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('Stable.id'))
    taskDate = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    stableuser_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('StableUser.id'))
    rating = db.Column(db.Integer())
    shift = db.Column(db.Text())
    db.UniqueConstraint('Task.taskDate', 'Task.shift')
    stable = relationship("Stable")
```

I want to find all tasks with a specific date, but I don't care about the time. When I query using this filter:

```
Task?q={"filters":[{"name":"taskDate","op":"eq","val":"2015-11-08T21:41:43"}]}
```

I get all tasks registered with that exact time and date. But when I filter like this:

```
Task?q={"filters":[{"name":"taskDate","op":"eq","val":"2015-11-08"}]}
```

I get no results at all. Is there a way to filter for date regardless of time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27872133/how-to-search-by-date